# Отловить пользователя историю браузера

Tags: php, javascript

Как отловить историю браузера, или посещенные сайты и подобное средствами js,php?... 
И возможно ли это вообще?

Или, может куки как то можно посмотреть пользователя?

Как то же сайты которые показыают рекламу, отслеживают куки и показывают мне рекламу тех товаров или услуг, какими я интересовался.. Как это они делают?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак, это была бы серьёзная дыра в безопасности/приватности.

Google AD (да и прочие подобные системы) отслеживает Вас по кукам, которые ставит для себя и, при заходе на любой сайт с его рекламой, он может сверять свои когда-то поставленные куки (IP, параметры браузера так же сверяются).

P. S. Злые языки говорят что подобные гиганты могут предоставлять накопленные сведения другим рекламщикам.